# Calculating the mean and variance of a periodic (circular) variable in R

Tags: r, mean, variance, periodicity

I have several variables in my dataset that represent daily timing of events across a week.

For example for two rows might look like:

```
t1 = c(NA,12.6,10.7,11.5,12.5,9.5,14.1)
t2 = c(23.7,1.2,NA,22.9,23.2,0.5,0.1)
```

I want to calculate the variance of these rows. To do this, I need the mean and because these are periodic variables, I've adapted the code from [this page](https://gist.github.com/jonesor/132f531a520c3b331543):

```
#This can all be wrapped in a function like this
circ.mean <- function(m,int,na.rm=T) {

   if(na.rm) m <- m[!is.na(m)]
   rad.m    = m*(360/int)*(pi/180)
   mean.cos = mean(cos(rad.m))
   mean.sin = mean(sin(rad.m))
   x.deg    = atan(mean.sin/mean.cos)*(180/pi)

   return(x.deg/(360/int))
}
```

This works as expected for `t2`:

```
> circ.mean(t2,24)
[1] -0.06803088
```

although ideally the answer would be `23.93197`. But for `t1`, it gives an incorrect answer:

```
> circ.mean(t1,24)
[1] -0.1810074
```

whereas using the normal `mean` function gives the right answer:

```
> mean(t1,na.rm=T)
[1] 11.81667
```

My questions are:

1) Is this "circular mean" code correct and if so, am I using it correctly?

2) I've had a stab my own `circ.var` function (see below) to calculate the variance of a periodic variable - will this produce the correct variances for all possible input timing vectors?

```
circ.var <- function(m,int=NULL,na.rm=TRUE) {

if(is.null(int)) stop("Period parameter missing")
if(na.rm) m <- m[!is.na(m)]
if(sum(!is.na(m))==0) return(NA)
n=length(m)
mean.m = circ.mean(m,int)
var.m = 1/(n-1)*sum((((m-mean.m+(int/2))%%int)-(int/2))^2)
return(var.m)

}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: (a) What are you basing your conclusion on that `circ.mean(t[1],24)` is incorrect but `mean(t[1],na.rm=T)` is correct? (b) Could do a tiny bit more work to make your question fully reproducible? Make the `t` definition copy/pasteable and handle `NA`s? When I run `circ.mean()` on your `t[1]` vector, I get `NA`.

Comment: Thanks for responding - I've made the requested changes. Apologies!

Comment: I'd also note that you seem to be having phase difficulties. I've never worked with circular means before, but it seems that points 180 degrees from each other are tricky... using your example of times, the mean of midnight and noon could be 6am or 6pm. You say `-0.1810074` is the wrong result, but `12 + -0.1810074` is `11.81899`---very close to your "right" result. Seems like the same issue as when you say you wish `-0.06803088` was instead `24 + -0.06803088 = 23.93197`

Comment: You're right in that the mean isn't unique for such a variable. I guess for most cases, the mean would be the value that would have the least sum distance from the elements, where the edge case is that they're perfectly distributed across the day (though that would be vanishingly rare in my data). I'm not sure why the code for a circular mean leads to a solution 180 degrees off the expected result though!

Comment: What you're doing in the variance function, `mean.m+(int/2))%%int`, you could do within the mean function. I think that will solve at least one of your problems.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor - if I replace `m` with `((m+(int/2))%%int)-(int/2)` it still gives the same answers for both `t1` and `t2`!

Comment: Something along those lines should work. Or at least `m %% int` to put everything in `[0, int)` (no negatives).

Comment: Thanks again for responding. Both t1 and t2 are invariant under %%int operation as both are already in the interval [0,int) so I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean `m`, I meant the result of the mean function. `return((x.deg/(360/int)) %% int)` will at least get you `23.93197` instead of `-0.06803088` for t2. Though you'll still be off by 180 degrees on t1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my old answer, as I believe there was a mistake in the solution I provided.

I've written a series of R scripts that I've made available at my [GitHub page](https://github.com/samuelejones/circstats) which should calculate the mean, variance and other stats.

Thanks to @Gregor for his help.